# Step function not returning lower AIC

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to apply the stats::step function to a lmer model.
I have a beginning model

```
modelComplex1 <- lmer(
log(value) ~ (time | ID) + time + (X1 + X2 + X3) ^ 2,
data = test,
REML = TRUE,
lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I then use the step function:

```
step(modelComplex1)
```

Which outputs:

```
Model found: log(value) ~ (time | ID) + time + X2 + X3
```

I then build said model:

```
modelStepComplex1 <- lmer(
log(value) ~ (time | ID) + time + X2+ X3,
data = test,
REML = TRUE,
lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

But then, when computing AIC:

```
> AIC(modelComplex1, modelStepComplex1)
                  df      AIC
modelComplex1     25 6944.118
modelStepComplex1  9 6950.111
```

I thought that the output model had to have a lower AIC, is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: `step` doesn't try interactions... only includes and excludes variables.

Comment: @user2974951 I thought interactions counted as variables themselves. Anyway, I tried adding X2:X3 manually in modelStepComplex1, but the AIC goes even higher to 6952.xx. Any ideas? I'm really lost as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The cause seems to be the fact the models were fit using REML, while the AIC uses ML. I'm not quite sure yet how to solve this, but for now it will have to suffice.

Comment: [REML or ML to compare two mixed effects models with differing fixed effects, but with the same random effect?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/reml-or-ml-to-compare-two-mixed-effects-models-with-differing-fixed-effects-but)

Comment: [lme4: Why is AIC no longer displayed when using REML](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131272/lme4-why-is-aic-no-longer-displayed-when-using-reml)